# why rspec test requires save and reload all time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This my example test block

```
it 'should redirect to account portfolio items page if user is creative and its first visit is false and sign in count is 1' do 
  @creative.first_visit = false
  @creative.sign_in_count = 1
  @creative.save!
  sign_in @creative
  get :index
  @creative.reload
  @creative.first_visit.should eql(true)
  response.should redirect_to account_portfolio_items_path
end
```

If I don't use save and reload test will be fail.Do you know why it happened and how can I handle with it?

This my test gems.

```
group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "factory_girl"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'shoulda'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds just fine. Normally your controller actions do database fetches to grab their data. In your test you might massage the data, but if you don't save it first, then your controller won't get the data you expect. Imagine this little scenario:

```
# in your test ...
user = User.new
get :index
assigns(:users).should eq [user]

# in your controller ...
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

This test will fail because the `user` in the test is never saved, so when the controller does `User.all`, it can't find the user.

Similarly with your test, when you update the attributes and your controller fetches the record, it doesn't know about your changes because they haven't been saved to the database. You definitely need to save your `@creative` model.

As for the reload, when you fetch a model from the database or make one brand new, it's attributes are stored in an in-memory instance. When you changed the `first_visit` attribute to false, you changed it in memory. When you saved the instance, it was applied to the database. When you called your `index` action, it updated the `Creative` instance it fetched to have `first_visit` be `true`. However, in your test you're still using the in-memory object which has it as `false`. The `reload` forces the object to be refetched from the database, which allows you to see it's current and updated attributes.

An alternative to reloading would be, if your controller set an instance variable, like `@creative`, to access it via the `assigns()` helper, like so:

```
get :index
assigns(:creative).first_visit.should eql(true)
```

That's saying that the instance variable `@creative` (that the controller set) will have a `first_visit` attribute set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `assigns` to access the instance variable from the controller in the RSpec rather than using reload. For more details on ideal way of writing specs, refer [Better Specs](http://betterspecs.org).